# Add a file using VBA MailEnvelope

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to add a file to a mail VBA, but I keep getting an error.

My code:

```
Sub MAIL()

 ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
  With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
   .Introduction = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Hereby I send you this file."
   .Item.To = "john.doe@gmail.com"
   .Item.Subject = "Daily file"
   .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Daily file.pdf")
 End With

End Sub
```

Error reads:

> Run-time error '438':
>   Object doesn't support this property or method

What can I do to get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a "item." was missing:

```
Sub MAIL()

 ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
  With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
   .Introduction = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Hereby I send you this file."
   .Item.To = "john.doe@gmail.com"
   .Item.Subject = "Daily file"
   .Item.Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Daily file.pdf")
 End With

End Sub
```